# Cancelling promise in nuxt-axios response interceptor

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

Basically, my question is the exact one here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/583. It can be done via `throw new axios.Cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');`.. But how can I do this in nuxt axios module?? I can not see it in the document and I tried `$axios.Cancel('Error')` but returned $axios.Cancel is not a constructor

Basically, the something like the snippet below is what I am looking for:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    throw new axios.Cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Emphasis on `throw new axios.Cancel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `@nuxtjs/axios` does not expose `axios.Cancel`, you could still import `axios` directly to get that symbol. Note `axios` is already a dependency of `@nuxtjs/axios`, so no extra dependency necessary.

*Example (tested with `@nuxtjs/axios` v5.11.0):*

```js
// plugins/axios.js
import { Cancel } from 'axios'

export default function ({ $axios }) {
  $axios.onResponse((response) => {
    if (response.code !== 200){
      throw new Cancel(response.msg)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This might be the best answer.. I have thought of using the actual axios but not like this.

Answer (score 0):

With `nuxt/axios` [v5.8.0](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/releases/tag/v5.8.0) [IsCancel](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/blob/191f869fa3ba1fe2243321c2b772e301ab9bf2fc/docs/usage.md#cancel-token) available

[v5.8.0](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/blob/191f869fa3ba1fe2243321c2b772e301ab9bf2fc/docs/usage.md#cancel-token) add `CancelToken` and `isCancel` to axios instance

Comment: I will appreciate if you can provide a snippet. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nuxt-axios does not have any exact equivalent but I found a work around.

**plugins/axios.js**

```
export default function({ $axios, req, store, redirect, app }, inject) {
  // const source = $axios.CancelToken.source()
  const timeout = process.env.API_TIMEOUT || 10000
  const errorHandling = function(error) {
    console.log(`API ${error}`)
    return new Promise(() => {})
  }
  $axios.onResponse((response) => {
    // Any condition that could be considered an response based on standard response
    if(response.code !== 200){
      throw response.msg
    }
  })
```

Comment: I am using 5.10.3.. Can you give me a snippet? Remember that I want to cancel the `response` and not the `request`